# vbcs.cache/edb.log locked by Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, version-control, visual-studio-2015

**when i try to commit (and push) code to visual studio online i get an error.**

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open
>   'P:/.../Solution/.../.vs/.../vbcs.cache/edb.log': The process cannot
>   access the file because it is being used by another process.

i've verified that the file is locked but ONLY while the visual studio is running, which means *the visual studio itself locks it*.

i'm using a preview of visual studio 2015 in a microsoft provided azure virtual machine.

**how to fix this error?**

restarting vm does not help.

Comment: Also seeing this in 
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 CTP
Version 14.0.22609.0 D14REL

Comment: I get the same issue (with vs 2015 ctp6) when using the Git provider. Bouncing VS seems to be the only solution. It shouldn't even by trying to treat those files as being source controlled, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Git users edit your .gitignore file enter "/.vs". This will ignore the folder with the locked file.

I have not tested it but adding this into the ignore file for another source control system (TFS, mercurial etc) should solve the issue.

Comment: This did the trick by adding this to the file solved the issues:  `#Ignore these directories  .vs/`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I try to pack a nuget package. I just closed all instances of Visual Studio and then deleted all files in that directory (/.../vbcs.cache/). It helped me.